Why does Directory.create in Dart return a Future<Directory>?
in flutter/dart Future<Directory> Directory.create({bool recursive = false}) return a Future<Directory>, but Why?
How does the Directory in the Future differ from the one I already have to run the directory creation?

@Clive Because create is an instance method on a Directory object; you must already start with a Directory object that represents the as-yet-uncreated filesystem directory.  In principle, it could return a Future<void> since you already have the Dart object corresponding to the desired filesystem entity.

You are correct that Directory.create returning a Future<Directory> instead of a Future<void> is redundant.  It could have returned Future<void>.  Compare to Directory.createSync, which does return void.
My guess would be that Directory.create probably returns a Future<Directory> instead of Future<void> to make chaining easier:
var directory = Directory('/some/path');
var events = (await directory.create()).watch();

Whereas the synchronous version could use the cascade operator:
var directory = Directory('/some/path');
var events = (directory..createSync()).watch();


About your suggests "It could have returned Future<void>" you are wrong.  Is also wrong  .createSync() is a void method.  Being Future<Directory> the .create() allows you once is created to do what you want with your directory (especially in not async methods avoiding use of await). The same could be createSync as well, it had to return a Directory.

@G3nt_M3caj What evidence do you have that I am wrong?  A Directory object is just some object that stores a directory path.  There is nothing special about it.  Directory('/some/path') will be the same Dart object before and after the filesystem entity is created.  There is no need for create or createSync to return a different Dart object.

In a context of null aware the better option is that it have to return e directory or directory info (but dart is not .NET). Is that what is needed. You are looking the directory as just a path but is not the maximum of life. There are a lot of thing someone have to know about i directory (tags, permissions, sub-directories list etc etc). If the directory doesn't exist you doesn't now anything about it.

@G3nt_M3caj None of that is relevant to the Dart Directory object.  As I said, the Dart object is just a wrapper around a filesystem path.  You can create a Directory('/some/path') regardless of whether /some/path exists or continues to be a valid path on the file system.

And none of you've written makes this answer wrong. createSync does return void. create could return a Future<void> without any significant difference (other than for some minor syntactic convenience like in the chaining case).  It might not be the API that is ideal to you, but that doesn't make this answer wrong.  If you think it's wrong, then provide code that demonstrates Directory.create() returning a (Future to a) Directory other than the one it was called on.

We have different approaches.In my opinion, Directory object as  result of both cases .create() (passing by Future) and .createSync() is always better than having nothing by its call, where you are forced doing tests if the method doesn't have occurred in some Exception due permissions or  other. Immagine a scenario in a Stateful widget where it changes it's state meanwhile you trying to create your directory. Registering an anonymous listener by then((dir) => ...) without use of await which block the UI you can continue to create your directory if doesn't exits without get in errors.

Otherwise variables as in your example doesn't guarantee that the task have to be completed (in complex scenarios as i said before - hoping that anyone try to create a directory inside of a Stateful widget, but using other approaches).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


How does the Directory in the Future differ from the one I already have...?

According to the documentation, it doesn't differ; it's the same object:

Returns a Future<Directory> that completes with this directory once it has been created. If the directory cannot be created the future completes with an exception.

(my emphasis)
Not that we don't trust the documentation, but it's easy to misinterpret things, so let's quickly prove it with experimentation. Bootstrap a cli project and change main to:
import 'package:cli/cli.dart' as cli;
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  var d = Directory('./testing');
  if (await d.exists()) {
    print('Directory already exists. Remove the directory before running.');
  } else {
    var d2 = await d.create();
    print(identical(d, d2)); // true
  }
}

When you run it, it outputs true; d and d2 refer to the same object.
Remember, I/O operations take ages (from a CPU's point of view), and create doesn't wait for the operation to finish (that's createSync), it returns a Future for when the operation finishes. Since that Future can have a value, they just chose to make that value the same Directory object you called create on.

The answer of your question is in comments.
  final List<int> bytes = [8, 16, 16, 32]; //immagine having something here by a web-stream
  Directory theNewDirectory = Directory("/ciao/fenomeno_di_turno");
  

  final File file = File("${theNewDirectory.path}/test.txt");
  file.createSync(); // get in error

  // OK . I'm going to create the directory.
  // But I'm blocking the application UI flow/thread
  // And what is the purpose of using await if there exists createSync();
  await theNewDirectory.create();
  file.createSync(); //Here can be DONE is created
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes!, flush: true);

  // NOTE THAT: ANYTHING BY THIS CODE ABOVE CAN BE GUARANTEE IN A STATEFUL WIDGET WHEN IT CHANGES ITS STATE
  // (ESPECIALLY IF YOU USE await's)


  // OTHERWISE (WHICH IS THE ANSWER OF YOUR QUESTION)
  // the purpose of use create() allows you to work on passed directory parameter 
  // read comments below
  if (!theNewDirectory.existsSync()) {
    theNewDirectory.create(recursive: true).then((Directory createdDir) {


      // HERE theNewDirectory, the first one, the original varible may NOT exists if your Stateful widget have changed its STATE.
      // this part always runs, once registered the listener .then((Directory createdDir) {..});
      
      final List<int> bytes = [8, 16, 16, 32];  
      final File file = File("${createdDir.path}/test.txt");
      file.createSync(); // Here you can do it as synchronously as you are in async mode by calling create()

      file.writeAsBytes(bytes!, flush: true);
    });
  }

Because if you are working in the main thread(for instance, using it in widget creation or state refresh) you can block it by I/O operations.
For that purpose you can use the asynchronous method Future<Directory> create({bool recursive = false}) of class Directory which gives a Future in which you can extract/await for the directory you need to be created, then use it for file creation or file/directory search etc etc..
Otherwise if you are sure of the fact that the context you are using
create doesn't block anything (UI related) you can use directly void createSync({bool recursive = false}) instead.
Even someone have problems with this answer (as I see) that remains here hoping that you and new SO users will understand the purpose of .create() and why it returns a Directory !!
